# Flask development server WSGI configuration

Tags: python, flask, reverse-proxy, wsgi, haproxy

In production, my flask application is not run at the domain root, but instead at https://domain:port/app. HAproxy handles this and also terminates SSL. I would like to do the same using the flask development server, but am having issues with `url_for` and `redirect`. Namely, `url_for` is excluding `/app` and `redirect(url_for(...))` ends up redirecting to http.

I understand that in production, the uWSGI config sets `SCRIPT_NAME` to `/app` to make `url_for` behave correctly. I believe it also does something to set `wsgi.url_scheme` to `https`, but am not sure.

Is there any way to set the WSGI config when running the dev server? All solutions I have seen involve things like custom middleware or ProxyFix, but then I have to do some sort of if switch to determine whether to apply these fixes, as they are unnecessary and break production. I am hoping there is a way to configure the WSGI environment with environment variables via the command line call to `flask run` so that both development and production are using the same code paths.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUFn-QVcmB8&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=14 this video might help you

Comment: I'm not a flask expert but the doc for [url_for](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) shows that you can add `_external=True,_scheme="https"` to the `url_for()` call. Maybe this could solve your issue?

Comment: I'd really rather not litter the code with extra params just to get something working in development. I am looking for the werkzeug equivalent of uWSGI's config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up writing a custom middleware to do the job. `__init__.py`:

```
class DevelopmentProxyFix():
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/app'
        environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    if app.config['ENV'] == "development":
        app.wsgi_app = DevelopmentProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
    ...
    return app
```